# is this for loop correct and infinite and why?

Tags: c++, for-loop

so i had this segment of code in my C++ test today:

```
for(int i=10;i++;i<15){cout<<i;}
```

what is this supposed to output? and why ?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want `for(int i=10; i<15; i++)`.

Comment: Currently, it would be UB with signed overflow.

Comment: Related: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: it's time to visit/revisit [the documentation of `for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).

Comment: If it’s supposed to output something in particular it’s because your teacher doesn’t understand undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop will run until either:

- its 2nd argument evaluates as 0/false.
- the loop body calls `break` or `return`, or throws an exception, or otherwise exits the calling thread.

The code you have shown **may or may not** loop *indefinitely*.  However, it will not loop the 5 times you might be expected, because the 2nd and 3rd arguments of the `for` statement are reversed.

The loop *should* look like this:

```
for(int i = 10; i < 15; i++)
```

However, in the form you have shown:

```
for(int i = 10; i++; i < 15)
```

The loop will continue running as long as `i` is not 0.  Depending on how the compiler interprets `i++` as a loop condition, it **may** recognize that this will lead to overflow and just decide to ignore `i` and make the loop run indefinitely, or it **may** actually increment `i` and let overflow happen.

In the latter case, on every loop iteration, `i` will be incremented, and eventually `i` will overflow past the maximum value that an `int` can hold.  At that time, `i` will *usually* wrap around to a negative value, since `int` is a signed type (though overflow behavior is not officially defined by the C++ standard, so the wrap is not guaranteed).  Then the loop will keep running since `i` is not 0, incrementing `i` each time until it eventually reaches 0, thus breaking the loop.

In either case, the loop will end up calling `cout << i` many thousands/millions of times (depending on the byte size of `int`), or call it forever until the program is terminated.

Comment: Signed `int` overflow is undefined though. Formally it's not certain that the loop will end.

Comment: Overflow might not be *officially* defined by the standard, but *in practice* it will usually overflow to negative on most platforms.

Comment: You're right that it's what will probably happen. But if you change the loop slightly, for example `std::cout << 'a';` and there's a good chance that the loop will be just optimized into a faster infinite loop. It may be misleading to say that it *will* wrap around, relying on the most common result of undefined behavior. The smallest change can make it untrue.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux true, though the question is not about what the code *might* do if the loop body were changed, the question is about what the code as shown *will* do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, in practice, compilers will realize that signed integer overflow is undefined behavior and short-circuit the loop altogether. Behold: https://godbolt.org/g/akhDFR

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it will never end in practice. The answer is wrong from both practical and theoretical standpoint.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I have a compiler (albeit an old one) that does not perform the kind of short-circuit optimization you describe, it does increment and test `i` on each iteration and does end the loop when `i` eventually reach 0, just as I described.

Comment: @SergeyA: this is highly compiler-specific behavior.  In practice, I have a compiler that DOES end the loop eventually.

Comment: This compiler is probably quite old and should not be used ;)

Comment: @SergeyA: Yes, it is quite old (2001, and I have to use it for my day job, upgrading is not an option [and not from a lack of trying!]). Still, one shouldn't rely on particular compiler optimizations, unless you can guarantee that you will never switch compilers, or change optimization settings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau no argument here! Of course one should not rely. But, knowing the practical effects of optimization (or undefined behavior in general) is extremely helpful when debugging issues.

Answer (score 0):

> what is this supposed to output? and why ?

That unconditionally do an **`signed`** `int` overflow.

So it is is Undefined behavior and can do anything.

Comment: In practice, it will most likely be infinite loop.

Comment: @SergeyA: The entire loop might also be optimized out as unreachable code (due to UB).

Comment: In provided example, compiler can not optimize for unreachable code removal, as compilers can not practically prove that `cout` doesn't have side effects which would make the code well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

For practical purposes, with any modern compiler this loop will continue forever. The reason for that is that the code is syntactically correct (however very incorrect semantically).

```
for(int i = 10; i++; i < 15)
```

means: start with i equal to 10. Check if `i++` is true (which it will be, since integers are convertible to booleans, with non-0 values converted to `true`). Proceed with loop body, on every iteration performing comparison of `i` and `15` (just comparing, not checking the result, this is your increment expression), incrementing `i` and checking if it is non-0.

Since compilers understand that signed integers never overflow, `i++` could never go to 0 when started with 10. As a result, optimizing compiler will remove the check altogether, and turn it into infinite loop.

Last, but not the least, learn to love compiler warnings. In particular, this code produces following:

```
<source>:4:29: warning: for increment expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     for (int i = 10; i++; i < 15) {
                           ~~^~~~
<source>:4:23: warning: iteration 2147483637 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
     for (int i = 10; i++; i < 15) {
                      ~^~
<source>:4:23: note: within this loop
     for (int i = 10; i++; i < 15) {
                       ^~
```

Comment: "*For practical purposes, this loop will continue forever*" - this is highly dependent on the compiler.  Not all compilers will optimize this code into an infinite loop (I have a compiler that doesn't).